# How to change the locale setting in Openshift v3 platform?

Tags: openshift, locale

By default Openshift v3 has the locale as en_US.UTF-8, I want to change this to en_IN.UTF-8. It looks like by default en_IN.UTF-8 is not installed. When I do "locale -a" on the POD it is not displaying "en_IN.UTF-8". Even setting the environment variables LANG and LC_ALL doesn't seem to work. Is there anyway to install the locale en_IN.UTF-8 to container?

Comment: Are you using a Source-to-Image (S2I) builder? If so, which one? Or are you running your own Docker image?

Comment: I'm using the default S2I builder that comes along with the openshift v3.

Comment: But which one? There are S2I builders for a range of different programming language, and how to you may update locale may depend on the language stack you are using as well.

Comment: I'm using python 2.7

Comment: Which of the variables starting with LC_ (LC_COLLATE, LC_CTYPE, LC_MESSAGES, LC_MONETARY, LC_NUMERIC, LC_TIME) are you really needing? What is the purpose in overriding it? It is already UTF-8 to begin with so that is usually sufficient.

Comment: I need LC_NUMERIC and LC_MONETARY. I want the decimal number formatting to be done according to the locale. So I can use locale.format.